# Ruby equivalent to Coffeescript shortened version of shorthand `if` operator

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, conditional-operator

In coffeescript you can do `name = a ? "bear"`. How can you do this in Ruby?

For those not aware of Coffeescript (v1.10), the statement above translates to Javascript as so:

```
name = typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null ? a : "bear"
```

In other words, if `a` is `undefined` or `null`, then assign `"bear"` to `name` (instead of assigning `a` to `name`)

Comment: For those of us who don't have the entire CoffeeScript Language Specification memorized, would you mind explaining what the "Ruby equivalent" is supposed to do?

Comment: Updated the description. Looks good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean `or`:

```
name = a || "bear"
```

To be precise, the following is an exact equivalent (there is no `undefined` in ruby):

```
name = a.nil? ? 'bear' : a
```

Comment: I think I must accept this, although what I actually need is Ruby equivalent to Javascript Boolean `or`. That is I need `(0 || "something")` to return "something", instead it returns `0`. Asked the wrong question I guess:)

Comment: @Aurimas note that `0 ? "something"` in CoffeeScript also returns `0`, it's not equivalent to JavaScript's `||`

Comment: Figures, totally wrong question, but maybe useful to somebody else. If you know the answer to my new question - feel free to elaborate. I have to wait 90min to ask new question.

Comment: `name = (a.nil? || a.empty? || a.zero?) ? 'bear' : a`?